# Whit is the stack size on Cygwin/Windows 64bit?

Tags: c, stack, size

i tried to search on the net but i didn't find anything about it. Only how to increase stack size and similar. I want to know the stack size on cygwin 64 bit for windows. I'm programming with C on netbeans and i tried to make a stack overflow to find the answer. From the code I obtained 43104 as result... Now, what this number is? bit-Kb-Mb?
I hope you could help me, sorry for my english :)

Comment: Just type `ulimit -s` in the terminal.

Comment: it gives to me 2025, it's on Kb, right?

Comment: Yes. If you type `ulimit -a` it will tell you the sizes with units.

Comment: another question, is there a method or a simple program to find this number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `cygwin` this is very easy with [`getrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct rlimit rl;

    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl) != 0)
        return -1;
    fprintf(stdout, "current: %ld kB\n\n", rl.rlim_cur / 1024);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works fine, thanks, the unique problem is that i've never seen some part of the code but it's not a problem. Are you sure that there is not another way (more simple)?

Comment: No I don't think there is, and I think this is very simple just 1 function call.

Comment: @user3721668 you know you can accept an answer if you think it helped you, don't you? I say that because I see you have no accepted answers, to do it click the check mark...

Comment: sorry for that, i'm a beginner on this site